# SQL Server HASHBYTES SHA2_512 and C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, encryption, sqlclr

If I run the following in SQL Server:

```
SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', 'THE CAT SAT ON THE MAT')
```

and then run this in C#

```
string test = WordFunctions.SHA512("THE CAT SAT ON THE MAT");
```

I get the same value back for both which is great. However, if I pass a string variable in my C# code so something like this:

```
string words = "THE CAT SAT ON THE MAT"

byte[] test
test = WordFunctions.SHA512(words);
```

then I don't get the same value?!

Any ideas?

the SHA512 function looks like this:

```
public static byte[] SHA512(String plaintext)
{
   // convert the passPhrase string into a byte array
   ASCIIEncoding AE = new ASCIIEncoding();
   byte[] passBuff = AE.GetBytes(plaintext);

   SHA512Managed hashVal = new SHA512Managed();
   byte[] passHash = hashVal.ComputeHash(passBuff);

   return passHash;
}
```

Comment: Do you have access to the code for `WordFunctions.SHA512`?

Comment: yes I do, sorry I should have included it! I will edit the original post.

Comment: So, ignoring SQL Server for a moment, you're saying `WordFunctions.SHA512("THE CAT SAT ON THE MAT");` and `WordFunctions.SHA512(words);` where `words = "THE CAT SAT ON THE MAT"` are returning *different things*? That seems very odd. btw, prefer `UTF8Encoding` as a general-purpose encoder.

Comment: Your first line of code should not compile, since SHA512 returns `byte[]`, not string. Any way, I tested this with your `SHA512` method code and both `byte` arrays are identical when I compare them.

Comment: @AakashM: he cannot use UTF8, he **must** use ASCII since the encoding must match SQL for `'THE CAT SAT ON THE MAT'`, which is ASCII.

Comment: @RemusRusanu I agree. I think I earlier commented to ask if there was any difference using a `N''` literal in SQL; but then I noticed that there are apparently inconsistent results *within just C#*, so I focused on that.

Answer (score 3):

The following code worked for me :

```
private static readonly Encoding Encoding1252 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);

public static byte[] SHA1HashValue(string s)
{
    byte[] bytes = Encoding1252.GetBytes(s);

    var sha1 = SHA512.Create();
    byte[] hashBytes = sha1.ComputeHash(bytes);

    return hashBytes;
}
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me to figure out why my C# produced SHA512 has was different to my sql server one