# 'ExecuteReader: Connection property has not been initialized.'

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, ado.net

I am new to C# and I have been trying to create a login using ADO.NET and WinForm but when I try logging in I get this error;

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'ExecuteReader: Connection property has not been initialized.'

I don't seem to know what is wrong.

```
private void bteAdminLog_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=DESKTOP-RCPAL7F;Initial Catalog=iCubeDB;Integrated Security=True";
    con.Open();

    String txtUser = txtUsername.Text;
    String txtPass = txtPassword.Text;

    string query = "SELECT * FROM AdminLogin WHERE Username =@user AND Password = @Pass";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@user", txtUser));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(" @Pass", txtPass));
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if(dr.HasRows == true)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Done");

    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("not done");
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ExecuteReader: Connection property has not been initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866046/executereader-connection-property-has-not-been-initialized)

Comment: no please, i have already read through it

Comment: Note that you're using `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` when you should be using `MySqlConnection` and `MySqlCommand`. That or you mistagged your question as `[mysql]` rather than `[sql-server]`. Also note that your second parameter is called `" @Pass"` with a leading space, rather than `"@Pass"`. This might cause you issues.

Comment: You should dispose your connection object with `using` also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `SqlCommand` didn't pass in with the `query` and `conn`

You should do it as:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
```

And for the `Parameters` part, you set the parameter with a **respective datatype includes length/size** (match with your database column) and then assign the value for each parameter:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@user", SqlDbType.Varchar, 10).Value = txtUser;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Pass", SqlDbType.NVarchar, 50).Value = /* hashed txtPass */;
```

The third parameter in `cmd.Parameters.Add()` is for datatype's size/length.

**UPDATED**:

[1st edit version]

As confirmed with Post Owner that the passwords stored are hashed in the database. Thus I remove the previous remark.

[2nd edit version]

Thanks for @Charlie 's concern, so I edit the answer to include the data type's length/size.

References:

1. [SqlCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0)
2. [Reason not to apply `AddWithValue()`](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: I passed the con and query to the SqlCommand  and it can connect to DB however i used HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', to encrypt the password at the DB side and now it keeps saying invalid user name or password. What can I do now please, am guessing I have to decrypt the password.

Comment: Hi @Yaw, I believe you are doing retrieving records from the `AdminLogin` table right? If yes, you need to hash user input's Password and compare with the Password in database. Please be sure that both passwords (user input & database record) have the same hash format. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you @Yong for taking the time to assist me. i only learnt how to use HASHBYTES('SHA2_512 to encrypt the password field in my DB this morning, how do i hash the password field in the form application.

Comment: Hi @Yaw, you are welcome, you can have a look on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15408971/sql-server-hashbytes-sha2-512-and-c-sharp) for hashing in C# or you can do hashing your Password in your SQL query. 

If you still face any difficulties, you may create another question for it as hashing part is not the same topic for this question. Thank you and have a great day.

Comment: respective datatype **and lengths**

Comment: @Charlieface, thanks for the comment. The lengths are also needed in the parameter data type as well.